# How to connect k8s, redis sentinel, flask_caching?

Tags: flask, kubernetes, caching, redis

I deployed a k8s redis sentinel using the Helm chart: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis

I did change only these values ( https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/redis/values.yaml ) :

```
auth:
  enabled: false
  sentinel: false
sentinel:
  enabled: true
  masterSet: mymaster
```

After the deployment, I got this message:

```
Redis&trade; can be accessed via port 6379 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:          
                                                                                                        
    redis.default.svc.cluster.local for read only operations                                            
                                                                                                        
For read/write operations, first access the Redis&trade; Sentinel cluster, which is available in port 26379 using the same domain name above.



To connect to your Redis&trade; server:

1. Run a Redis&trade; pod that you can use as a client:

   kubectl run --namespace default redis-client --restart='Never'  --image docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.6-debian-10-r103 --command -- sleep infinity

   Use the following command to attach to the pod:

   kubectl exec --tty -i redis-client \
   --namespace default -- bash

2. Connect using the Redis&trade; CLI:
   redis-cli -h redis -p 6379 # Read only operations
   redis-cli -h redis -p 26379 # Sentinel access

To connect to your database from outside the cluster execute the following commands:

    kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/redis 6379:6379 &
    redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
```

This is working nicely:

```
 kubectl get pods
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
redis-node-0   2/2     Running   0          2m23s
redis-node-1   2/2     Running   0          71s
redis-node-2   2/2     Running   0          43s
```

But regarding access - to summarize - I have two options to access redis:

1. read-only access at redis.default.svc.cluster.local:6379
2. read-write access at redis.default.svc.cluster.local:26379 (some kind of sentinel access, in the docs:

```
Master-Replicas with Sentinel
When installing the chart with architecture=replication and sentinel.enabled=true, it will deploy a Redis™ master StatefulSet (only one master allowed) and a Redis™ replicas StatefulSet. In this case, the pods will contain an extra container with Redis™ Sentinel. This container will form a cluster of Redis™ Sentinel nodes, which will promote a new master in case the actual one fails. In addition to this, only one service is exposed:

Redis™ service: Exposes port 6379 for Redis™ read-only operations and port 26379 for accessing Redis™ Sentinel.
For read-only operations, access the service using port 6379. For write operations, it's necessary to access the Redis™ Sentinel cluster and query the current master using the command below (using redis-cli or similar):

SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name <name of your MasterSet. e.g: mymaster>
This command will return the address of the current master, which can be accessed from inside the cluster.

In case the current master crashes, the Sentinel containers will elect a new master node.
```

Now I want to connect my Flask caching module to it: https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

As you can see, there is an option to connect to redis sentinel, however I have no idea how. This is the code I have:

```
from flask_caching import Cache
cache = Cache(app, config={
  'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisSentinelCache', 
  'CACHE_REDIS_SENTINELS': ['redis.default.svc.cluster.local'], 
  'CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER': 'mymaster'}
)
```

My questions are:

1. What should be in param CACHE_REDIS_SENTINELS? Should I somehow get IP addresses of each node and get those there?
2. What should be in param CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER? Is it "mymaster" (sentinel -> masterSet?)
3. Should I connect always to the read-write server (in this case, will other replicas be used)? Or do I need to adjust my app in this way: if I write I always use the sentinel access at port 26379, and in the case that I read I connect always to the read-only 6379 port? Do I need to maintain 2 connections?

Thank you

EDIT: I was digging into the code of flask_caching and it seems this works OK (but I am not sure if replicas are used):

```
import time
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache

config = {
    "DEBUG": True,          # some Flask specific configs
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisSentinelCache',
    'CACHE_REDIS_SENTINELS': [
        ['redis.default.svc.cluster.local', 26379]
    ],
    'CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER': 'mymaster'
}
app = Flask(__name__)
# tell Flask to use the above defined config
app.config.from_mapping(config)
cache = Cache(app)

@app.route("/")
@cache.cached(timeout=5)
def index():
    return "%d\n" % time.time()

app.run()
```

EDIT2:

Indeed, a bit digging into flask_caching and it uses replicas as well:

in file `flask_caching/backends/rediscache.py`

The code is getting hosts for write and read access:

```
        self._write_client = sentinel.master_for(master)
        self._read_clients = sentinel.slave_for(master)
```

Cheers!

EDIT3:

Example with redis driver:

```
from redis.sentinel import Sentinel
sentinel = Sentinel([('redis.default.svc.cluster.local', 26379)])
redis_conn = sentinel.master_for('mymaster')
redis_conn_read = sentinel.slave_for('mymaster')

redis_conn.set('test', 'Hola!')
print(redis_conn_read.get('test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

```
import time
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache

config = {
    "DEBUG": True,          # some Flask specific configs
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisSentinelCache',
    'CACHE_REDIS_SENTINELS': [
        ['redis.default.svc.cluster.local', 26379]
    ],
    'CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER': 'mymaster'
}
app = Flask(__name__)
# tell Flask to use the above defined config
app.config.from_mapping(config)
cache = Cache(app)

@app.route("/")
@cache.cached(timeout=5)
def index():
    return "%d\n" % time.time()

app.run()
```

For more details see my original question (EDIT and EDIT2).